# System logs me off after I close laptop's screen

Tags: laptop, screen, logging

Hello everybody I have very anoying issue with my ubuntu 14.04. When I close the screen of my laptop, the system logs me off and I need to enter my password to log in again. That would not be a problem, but I use my laptop as router for my XB360 console, so laptop has to be loged in all the time to allow me connect with Xbox Live. I have already switch the option of freezing the computer after closing the screen, but it still log me off and it disconnects me with Xbox Live.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Run this in a terminal:

```
gksudo gedit /etc/systemd/logind.conf
```

or

```
sudo nano /etc/systemd/logind.conf
```

Then look for the value `#HandleLidSwitch=suspend` and **remove the "#"** at the beginning and change it to:

> HandleLidSwitch=**ignore**

To apply the changes  run:

```
sudo restart systemd-logind
```

More info you can find here:
http://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/logind.conf.html