# Laptop goes to sleep right after boot with lid closed and external monitor connected

Tags: power-management

The issue is following: laptop (HP6570p) with Kubuntu 14.04 installed, lid closed, external monitor is connected. Reboot. Laptop shows KDM login screen for a seconds and immediately goes to sleep.

Open lid wakes it up. Login. Then close the lid again. Everything is fine.

Power option set to "Do nothing" when lid is closed.

Any suggestions?

Comment: You can try this http://askubuntu.com/a/474357/265974

Comment: you can also look at [https://help.ubuntu.com/community/LaptopLidAndDockScripts](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/LaptopLidAndDockScripts)

Answer (score 5):

The problem appears to be you have one setting for when user is logged in and another setting when you're at the greeter (lightdm).

I solved this problem by editing `/etc/UPower/UPower.conf` and changing `IgnoreLid=false` to `IgnoreLid=true` at the end of the file.

After restarting, closing the lid didn't put the computer to sleep anymore.

I used this question as reference: [Stop laptop from suspending when closing lid in lightdm](https://askubuntu.com/questions/85705/stop-laptop-from-suspending-when-closing-lid-in-lightdm)

Note: someone asked there if this wouldn't disable the lid behavior for every users. I really don't know.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to address this problem on my Thinkpad W520, running Kubuntu 22.04.4, by editing /etc/systemd/logind.conf as root:

```
sudo su
nano /etc/systemd/logind.conf
```

Uncomment and update the values for the following:

```
HandleLidSwitch=ignore
HandleLidSwitchExternalPower=ignore
```

To save and exit nano:

```
Control-O
Control-X
```

Rebooting the system with the lid closed now permit the system to remain active vs. going into sleep mode.