# During halt system hibernates on lid closed

Tags: laptop, power-management, shutdown, suspend

I use xubuntu 14.04 64bit on Lenovo g510.

I disabled hibernation on lid closed in xfce power manager.

> On lid closed: do nothing.

It works. I can close and open the lid and system is not hibernating.

Problem occurs when I want to halt or reboot. When I close lid too fast, computer hibernates. I can notice that, because when I open the lid after many hours, system goes back from hibernation and it is fishing halt.

How can solve this?

Comment: Try this http://askubuntu.com/a/474357/265974